# Copy on modify in R: running a block or line by line

Tags: r

I've a problem with the copy-on-modify topic.
I'm studying the book "Advanced R" by Hadley Wickham and I don't have the same results of him in all cases.
In particular if i try:

```
x <- sample(10)
.Internal(inspect(x))
```

When I run the code line by line, my result is :

```
@0x0000028de51b79f0 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(7)] (len=10, tl=0) 4,1,2,10,5,...
```

but if I run the two lines together I obtain:

```
@0x0000028de396b398 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(1)] (len=10, tl=0) 6,9,7,10,2,...
```

In addition if I do the same thing with the code:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
tracemem(x)  
y <- x
y[[3]] <- 4L
y[[3]] <- 5L
```

running line by line I obtain :

```
"<00000297C9798EB8>"
tracemem[0x00000297c9798eb8 -> 0x00000297c84cb470]: 
tracemem[0x00000297c84cb470 -> 0x00000297c9384560]:
```

but running all the block together:

```
 "<00000297C8E56AF8>"
tracemem[0x00000297c8e56af8 -> 0x00000297c8e56918]:
```

So i don't really get the point why these results are different running line by line or all the block together.

Thank to all the people that can help me,
Have a nice day

Comment: can you try again the first part with setting seed for the random number generator ? ie add set.seed(1) as first command you execute, either line by line or together? Do you still get different results?

Comment: @Waldi yes! I've tried it but there are no differences!

Comment: can you link the paragraph of Hadey's book you're refering to and what are you exacty doing when you run lines together (select all + ctrl-R?)

Comment: @Waldi For the first part I got the code from https://www.brodieg.com/2019/02/18/an-unofficial-reference-for-internal-inspect/#:~:text=R%20implements%20a%20copy%2Don,do%20not%20modify%20their%20arguments. . For the second part I got https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#copy-on-modify (2.3). When I run the lines together the lines I source the entire code or I highlight the part that I want to run and I run it!

Comment: OK, got your point! but sorry, no answer on my side. By the way, I'm using R4.x, so the [NAM] token has been replaced by [REF] token